# How to link to specific tab page in JQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a set of tabs on a page in JQuery mobile. On a separate page, I would like to create links that specify which tab window to display.

Currently, it seems like linking to a tab's ID does not do anything unless it is on the same page. (The tab headers work just fine.) They just do not work from a separate 'page'. I am not sure if this is an oversight in the framework, or if I am missing something simple!

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bw2rehhd/).

```
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="front">

  <div data-role="content" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#main">main link</a>
    <a href="#p1">tab 1</a>
    <a href="#p2">tab 2</a>

  </div>

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="main">

  <div data-role="tabs" class="tabs ui-content">
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#p1" data-ajax="false">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#p2" data-ajax="false">Tab 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="p1" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
      Tab 1 <br />
      <a href="#front">Return</a>

    </div>
    <div id="p2" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
      Tab 2 <br />
      <a href="#front">Return</a>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do a example to you, see this in [jsFiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/rboschini/bw2rehhd/3/).

I have bind links with special tags, to detect and trigger click.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[data-target]').on('click',function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
    $('a[data-info="'+ target +'"]').click();
  });
});
```

But, this method have a problem, the time of .click() is quickly than render tab, then i resolve that with a little timer.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('a[data-info="'+ target +'"]').click();
},500)
```

let me know with works.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! I am now trying to make the button stay blue once it is clicked.

Comment: I am getting closer! https://jsfiddle.net/bw2rehhd/4/ I will have to look through the JQuery mobile documentation and do this properly, haha.

Comment: set timeout to more 400ms, fix to 500ms and try again